# Horizontal scroll issue in Jquery click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some items in a horizontal scrolling div. What i am trying is to move scroll left and right on certain click events.I done some coding but after completing the scroll it takes extra space on click event please check.

```js
$('.btnleft').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.PaymentScroll').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=198px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('.btnright').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.PaymentScroll').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=198px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn-left"></span>
<span class="btn-right"></span>
<div class="scrollDiv">
  <div class=internal>
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 2
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 3
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is some CSS missing I suppose...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].